# Representing a transformation from C to C with respect to the basis 1, i

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I am having trouble understanding why the transformation: $ T(z) = (3+4i)z$ from C to C can be represented by the matrix
$ \begin{bmatrix} 
3, -4 \\
4, 3 
\end{bmatrix}$
with respect to the basis
$ \begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\
i
\end{bmatrix}$.

Isn't the following matrix the correct matrix for the transformation? I believe it returns the correct vector.
$ \begin{bmatrix} 
3, 0 \\
0, 4 
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multipy $ \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -4\\
4 & 3
 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a\\
b
 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3a - 4b\\
4a+3b
 \end{bmatrix} $

Now consider transformation: $ T(a+bi) = (3+4i)(a+bi) = 3a-4b+(4a+3b)i $

Hence matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 3 & -4\\
4 & 3
 \end{bmatrix}$ is correct.

Comment: @Timbuc no, there are exactly 4

Comment: Yes. I assume the OP is taking *the transpose* of the coefficients matrix, not the matrix itself, as he wrote $\;T(1)\;$ instead of $\;(1)T\;$ .

Comment: I believe T represents transformation in this case. This is from page 348 of Otto Bretscher's Linear Algebra with Applications

Comment: @120MinuteMan Of course it represents a (linear) transformation: it is written sepcifically in the question, and what else could it represent?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're taking $\;\Bbb C\;$ as a vector space over $\;\Bbb R\;$ . Apply $\;T\;$ on the basis elements:

$$\begin{align}&T(1)=3\cdot1+4\cdot1i\\{}\\&T(i)=-4\cdot1+3\cdot i\end{align}\;\;\implies\;\;[T]=\begin{pmatrix}3&\!\!-4\\4&3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3&4\\\!\!-4&3\end{pmatrix}^t$$

Comment: If $ T(1) = 3 + 4i $ the first column should be \begin{bmatrix} 3\\
4
 \end{bmatrix}

Comment: Yep. I already edited and wrote both possibilities, one for when the function's applied on the left, the second (with the transpose) when the function's applied on the right.